# Minha conexão localhost esta demorando

Tags: node.js, servidor, express.js

Criei um servidor NodeJS com express mas quando tento acessar http://localhost:3000 a página nunca carrega, fica carregando somente.

```
const http = require('http')

const express = require('express')

http.createServer(express).listen(3000, () => console.log("Servidor rodando local na porta 3000"));
```

Comment: Vc provavelmente tem um middleware q nao chama a funcao `next`. Seria interessante vc editar a pergunta colocando o seu código atual para q possamos te ajudar melhor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seguindo a documentação oficial do [express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) não devemos mais usar o modulo http das bibliotecas padrões do nodejs, pois caso você preste atenção no codigo `app.listen`, tudo que ele faz é criar um `http.createServer()` e chama o `listen()` para ele, ou seja, usar o novo modo do express apenas lhe encurta tempo e lhe ajuda a não ter que usar o modulo http diretamente.

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

Answer (score 1):

não uses http, já que estas a usar o express

assim

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.listen(3000,()=> console.log("Servidor online");
```

Comment: Por que não usar http? Não é algo bom?

Comment: Não é muito a questão de não ser bom, mas de não fazer muito sentido, usar http quando se usa o express, pois express já faz tudo que o html faz

Comment: Desculpa, mas eu não entendi a relação de Express com HTML, nesse caso